# Safe partial function

Tags: scala

I want to convert a partial function into a "safe" partial function, i.e. `PartialFunction[T,R]` into a `PartialFunction[T,Try[R]]`, is there any better way than the following implementation?

```
def safe[T,R](pf:PartialFunction[T,R]):PartialFunction[T,Try[R]]=new PartialFunction[T, Try[R]]{
  def isDefinedAt(t:T) = pf.isDefinedAt(t)
  def apply(t:T) = Try(pf.apply(t))
}
```

Comment: How about [PartialFunction's](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.PartialFunction) `lift` method. Turns a `PartialFunction[A,B]` into `A => Option[B]`

Comment: `Option[T]` is definitely the right way here.

Answer (score -1):

You can define `safe` using a `for` expression:

```
def safe[T,R](pf:PartialFunction[T,R]) = PartialFunction {
  (t:T) => for(a <- Try(pf(t))) yield a
}
```

Or using an implicit class:

```
object SafeImplicit {
  implicit class Safe[T,R](pf: PartialFunction[T,R]){
    def safe(t: =>T) = for(a<-Try(pf(t))) yield a
  }
}

import SafeImplicit.Safe
def f: PartialFunction[Int, String] = {case 1 => "one"}
def g: PartialFunction[Int, String] = {case 1 => "a".toInt;"one"}

f.safe(1)          // Success(one)
f.safe(2)          // Failure(scala.MatchError: 2 ...)
f.safe("a".toInt)  // Failure(java.lang.NumberFormatException ...)
g.safe(1)          // Failure(java.lang.NumberFormatException ...)
```